# Vertically Align mat-checkbox and mat-form-field | Angular Material | Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I am trying to implement text Fields and checkbox side by side. Something like this.
[image]

But, the problem is `<mat-form-field>` and `<mat-checkbox>` is not vertically aligning.
How do I go forward by aligning both of them vertically?

Here is the code:

```
<mat-card>
    <mat-card-title>
        Family Information
    </mat-card-title>
    <form [formGroup]="familyInfo">
        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="flex-start" fxLayoutGap="40px">
            <mat-form-field fxFlex="10%">
                <mat-label>Contact Name</mat-label>
                <input matInput>
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field fxFlex="10%">
                <mat-label>Relation Type </mat-label>
                <mat-select>
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let relationType of relationTypes" [value]="relationType" color="accent">
                        {{relationType}}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field fxFlex="10%">
                <mat-label>Gender </mat-label>
                <mat-select>
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let gender of genders" [value]="gender" color="accent">
                        {{gender}}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field fxFlex="10%">
                <mat-label>Date Of Birth</mat-label>
                <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dateOfBirth" formControlName="dateOfBirth">
                <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dateOfBirth"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                <mat-datepicker #dateOfBirth></mat-datepicker>
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-checkbox formControlName="isDependent">Is Dependent</mat-checkbox>

            <div fxFlex="100%"></div>
            <mat-card-actions>
                <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" class="align-right-button">
                    Save
                </button>
            </mat-card-actions>
        </div>
```

I tried using the `<mat-form-field>`, but as per angular material docs. `<mat-checkbox>` cannot be a part of `<mat-form-field>`

Comment: can you please reproduce this in a fiddle with your css?

Answer (score 2):

You have to position the checkbox manually. There is no other way to line the elements. Something like `align-self: center` for mat-checkbox.

Please be aware that `mat-form-field` has some custom paddings/margins. So, to have the perfect fitment you will need to inspect the element and add a couple px at the top. Depending on font-size it differs.

Hopefully, it will help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I deal with it:

```
<mat-checkbox class="checklist-leaf-node" style="width: 100%;" #checkBox formControlName="isDependent"> Is Dependent</mat-checkbox>
<mat-form-field style="width: 0%;">
   <input matInput class="pointer" type="text">
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

found a workaround using css and separating the mat-checkbox text into its own label tag with position relative

```
<mat-checkbox style="position:relative;top:-20px;left:15px;">
    </mat-checkbox>
    <label style="position:relative;left:27px;top:-10px;">
      some long text
    </label>
```

Some case below css in main stylesheet seem to work

```
.mat-checkbox.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-inner-container {
```

margin: 2px 8px auto 0;
}